# ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type PasswordExpirationDate

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

I am trying to fetch data for the field `PasswordExpirationDate` from Active Directory but getting this error

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type PasswordExpirationDate
```

I am using below to connect to AD:

```
conn.search(search_base=base,
                    search_filter=filter,
                    search_scope=SUBTREE,
                    attributes=fields,
                    paged_size=self.page_size,
                    paged_cookie=cookie)
        response = conn.response_to_json()
```

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Where are you specifying "PasswordExpirationDate"?

Comment: I don't think there is a field like that, which corresponds to the error. Expiration date depends on many things, you can get it from a (computed) field named "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed".